# Parameterization in Junit

Tags: java, junit, junitparams

I am learning JUnit and I am getting the following error for the following point in the code:

> The attribute method is undefined for the annotation type
>   Parameterized.Parameters

The method is:

```
@Test  
@Parameters(method = "getMoney")
private static final Object[] getMoney() {
    return new Object[]{
        new Object[]{10, "USD"},
        new Object[]{20, "EUR"}
    };  
}
```

I have added JUnit and JUnitParams to build path.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `Parameters` class. Please use

```
import junitparams.Parameters;
```

Comment: Yes all working now- i was using                                                                  import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

Comment: Stefan Thank you so much for that. I was using

Comment: I was using -import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;